# Ionic + Firebase Facebook returning Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration:

Tags: facebook, firebase, ionic-framework

Ok I have setup the app to have 
https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/scorching-heat-3755.firebaseio/auth/facebook/callback
http://127.0.0.1/
http://localhost/

in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs and I keep getting

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What app domain have you in the App Settings? If you have firebase.com then localhost and 127.0.0.1 is invalid. You should use test apps for testing rather than your prod app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: I am using firebase,  here are the url in oauth redirect uri's https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<My app name>/auth/facebook/callbackRemove https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback  and in basic settings i have set the domain to firebase and the site url to https://auth.firebase.com/v2/SMARTCITY/auth/facebook/callback and still I am getting the same error(specified above by the asker.  Can anyone help me out here